# Index spanning multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to place an index on an expression containing fields of multiple tables. So for example an index to speed up an query of the following form:

```
SELECT *, (table1.x + table2.x) AS z
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
ORDER BY z ASC
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No it's not possible to have an index on many tables, also it really wouldn't guarantee speeding up anything since you won't always get an Index Only Scan. What you really want is a [materialized view](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views) but pg doesn't have those either. You can try implementing it yourself using triggers [like this](http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views) [or this](http://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/events/69.en.html).

---

### Update

As noted by @petter. The materialized views [were introduced in 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

Comment: You can create an index on multiple columns in *one* table. You can't create an index on columns in two *different* tables. I'm pretty sure this is true for all current SQL dbms, not just PostgreSQL.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports Materialized Views as of version 9.3: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Comment: @petter 9.3 wasn't around when I wrote that. Updated anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible in *any* currently shipping SQL dbms. Oracle supports [bitmap join indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5011.htm#i2077608), but that might not be relevant. It's not clear to me whether you want an index on only the join columns of multiple tables, or whether you want an index on arbitrary columns of joined tables.

To determine the *real* source of performance problems, learn to read the output of PostgreSQL's [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html).

Comment: Don't really have an performance issue. Most time is consumed by sorting on an expression and I hoped to be able to speed up the query even further using a table spanning index. The rest of the time is mostly consumed by index scans and hash joins and I don't think I can speed up those. My question was mainly because of curiosity  since I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: No, like Jakub Kania said, the workaround in PostgreSQL requires triggers. (Because PostgreSQL doesn't yet support materialized views.)

Comment: @EwoutKleinsmann well, if you'd really want to I guess there's also a chance to create a function(table1.id,table1.x) that would do a query on table2 and lie it's immutable so an index can be created on it. But it would be unreliable because it wouldn't update automaticaly, unreliable because it's not guaranteed it would be used and slow because there are no IOS on functions  and so right rows would be choosen and then the function would be run again. So I guess if you'd select top 10 from 5 milion rows ordered by t1.x+t2.x it would be faster but a trigger could do the same much better.

Comment: Isn't the trigger more desirable & less complex than materialized views anyway for simple cases & performance reasons? Assuming the whole VIEW is _materialized_, it's a lot cheaper to just copy over an expression or value to a table with a trigger and then reference that. I'm sure there is a way to avoid certain aspects of materialization, but the straightforward approach of simply _materializing_ is not cheap and will slow a lot of things down with duplication. Perhaps Oracle & MSSQL can use/inherit the underlying tables for verbatim table column references, but I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: It's not *the* trigger. You need triggers for every action on every underlying table. That could be a *lot* of procedural code. Being able to replace a lot of procedural code with a single SQL statement is, I think, more desirable and less complex. Whether that's cheaper to execute is a quality-of-implementation issue. PostgreSQL 9.3 supports `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW`, and 9.4 should extend its usability.

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiple triggers. That wasn't my focus, though.  Every implementation of materialized views I've seen:

1. Duplicates the data.
2. Is out of sync until a refresh.

#1. is particularly bad. As a practical matter that may not be a QOI issue; unless some implementation can solve #1, the use of triggers would be more desirable in terms of space complexity. #2 is debatable. Replaying from a log without locks and MVCC sounds nice if you're not worried about something being stale. If you just need a column to order by like the example, needing to create a full duplicate is unfortunate

Comment: Oracle has supported this for many years "bitmap join indexes".  The appropriate join is part of the index declaration.  They are slower to update, but make for blindingly fast queries. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96520/indexes.htm