# Rails & Postgreql: Index on joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I run a Rails app with postgresql as a database. I do a lot of joined searches and the queries tend to be quite slow. I don't quite understand if it just the nature of joined searches that makes the queries slow or if I have failed to make an accurate index for them.

Example (my queries are usually more complex but this shows what I mean):

```
Product belongs_to :store
Store has_many :products
Store.is_open :boolean
Product.has_image :boolean
```

I make queries like:

```
Store.where(:is_open => true).products.where(:has_image => true)
```

Do I:

1. Make indexes only Store and Product exclusively like:

   add_index :stores, :is_open
   add_index :products, :has_image

This is what I do now.

OR

2. Can I make a joined index that includes both tables?

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26251892/525478

Comment: Short answer: "no".  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402225/index-spanning-multiple-tables-in-postgresql

Comment: Thanks, you can put that as an answer if you want. I have to make it speedier in other ways, I guess. I have just started experimenting with bullet gem.