# How to generate indexes for related fields on Django models?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Say we're building a Django-based site that clones Medium.com's URL structure, where you have users and articles. We'd probably have this model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = models.CharField()
```

We want to be able to build URLs that look like `/<username>/<slug>/`. Since we're going to have billions of articles and zillions of pageviews, we want to put an index on that model:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['user__username', 'slug'])
    ]
```

But this causes the `makemigrations` command to fail with the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Article has no field named 'user__username'. The app cache isn't ready yet, so if this is an auto-created related field, it won't be available yet.
```

So, plain vanilla `models.Index` doesn't support relational lookups like a QuerySet does. How would I add an index like this? Let's assume PostgreSQL, if that's helpful.

Comment: Have you considered appending the primary key, or some other indexed unique field, to the slug and querying by that?

Comment: @pocket kings Not a bad idea. I'll consider that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can't make multi-table index according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402225/index-spanning-multiple-tables-in-postgresql).

So if it's not possible in the database, I don't see how can Django offer this feature...

What you can do to make your queries more efficients is an index using `user_id` and `slug`.

Answer (score 0):

Django index meta class mainly provide declarative options for indexing table fields,

you can create an index using several field of a model or create different index for every fields of the model. you just don't have to provide user foriegnkey field name attribute which generate automatic user_id index migrations

```
 migrations.AddIndex(
            model_name='candidates',
            index=models.Index(fields=['user'], name='candidates__user_id_569874_idx'),
        ),
```

you can also set the index name in the model meta, and db_tablspace as well if needed.